# использование TextBox.GetCharacterIndexFromPoint для установки SelectionStart

Tags: wpf, позиционирование, textbox

При установке SelectionStart текстбокса (также при вычислении SelectionLength) с использованием функции GetCharacterIndexFromPoint - никогда не получим позицию за последним символом (при попытке установить курсор в конец текста). Эта функция при указании точки уже после текста вернет индекс последнего символа, т.е. получаем позицию ПЕРЕД последним символом. Как в коде решить - что действительно хотел пользователь - установить курсор за или перед последним символом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот такая функция вернет нам позицию в зависимости от расположения точки нажатия мыши на текстбоксе:

```
private int GetTxtCharIndex(TextBox txt, Point point)
{
    int idx = txt.GetCharacterIndexFromPoint(point, true);
    if (txt.Text.Length > 0)
    {
        Rect rect = txt.GetRectFromCharacterIndex(idx);
        if (rect.Right < point.X)
            idx++;
    }
    return idx;
}
```